# AZDO Release Pipeline Gate Success Criteria for Rest-API

Tags: javascript, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to use the `Release Pipeline Gate` feature using an Invoke `REST API`. I am getting the Response successfully, however, I have issues with the success criteria.

The result I am getting from the API Call:

```
{"projectStatus":{"status":"NONE","conditions":[],"periods":[]}}
```

Now the issue I am having is with setting up the criteria. If it was per say only `{"status":"NONE","conditions":[],"periods":[]}` it would've been easy as `eq(root['@status'], 'NONE')` would've worked, but what can I do in the case above?

I've tried absolutely everything and nothing works. I've followed a lot of examples but I couldn't find an example like this one.

Could you please assist?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer your own question. That helps future users find the right solution to the problem.

Comment: you could accept your solution as an answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks. If not, please let us know if you would like further assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many tests, I managed to find the solution:

### eq(jsonpath('$.projectStatus.status')[0],'NONE')

Works flawlessly...